# Summary of All of Statistics in a useful mind map

Tags: self-study, data-visualization, references

Is there a good mind map to summarize all the important concepts in statistics in a useful manner so that a beginner can decide which topics he has covered, which he needs to cover in short term, which he needs to cover in long term and which he can just ignore for sure or at least replace it with some blackbox software for all practical purposes?

For example, machine learning has a very nice mind map by Jason Brownlee.

[image]

The mind map does not need to go into too much detail and include low-level topics. Just high-level topics like hypothesis testing, ANOVA, regression, experiment design etc. should suffice. But it should not miss any topic of mathematical statistics covered in both undergrad and grad level courses.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430259/what-are-the-branches-of-statistics/431628